# I programmatically created rectangles, and added buttons on storyboard and the buttons are getting covered by the rectangles. How do I fix that?

Tags: ios, swift

I programmatically created rectangles, and added buttons on storyboard and the buttons are getting covered by the rectangles. How do I fix that?

```
import UIKit

class interestViewController: UIViewController {

var squareView: UIView!

var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!

var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    squareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))

    view.addSubview(squareView)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @matt mentioned it subViews and basically Views are ordered in the window. So you have different way to do what you want :

You can insert your rectangle at a given `index` if you know it :

`self.view.insertSubview(squareView atIndex:index)`

If you have a reference to your `UIButton` you can either do :

`self.view.insertSubview(square, belowSubview:button)`

or after adding your `squareView` using :

`self.view.addSubview(squareView)`

Call the following :

`self.view.sendSubviewToBack(squareView)`

All this methods are referenced in the  [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/subviews)

Answer (score 0):

Views have a layering order. After you add a rectangle, move it to the back of the layering order.

Comment: there is no option for the rectangle on the storyboard. http://puu.sh/hr18r/e45cb04323.png

Comment: @user3358638 that's because you didn't create it in the storyboard. Use `insertSubview:atIndex:`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code .

```
 import UIKit

    class interestViewController: UIViewController {

    var squareView: UIView!

   @IBOutlet weak var btntemp: UIButton!

    var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!

    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

    var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        squareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))

        view.addSubview(squareView)

    // add button on squareView 
       squareView.addSubview(btntemp)


    }
```